# Exclude one phtml file from cache

Tags: cache, search, block-cache

How should I go about creating a list of phtml files that I would like to be excluded from the standard magento caching system?

*Some Context:
I have a search bar in the header of a magento site. When a search term is entered another php file is rendered through ajax with a list of relevant results.
When I turn off the block cache it works perfectly but when I don't turn it off the list of results appear as normal but if you click on them they all bring you to the same product.
So unless I'm missing something I assume removing this phtml file from cache will fix my problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to set the Caching lifetime of the black behind it to zero.
Inchoo did [an article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-block-caching/) about this I used a long while back.

Basically you need to the following to the block

```
protected function _construct()
{
   $this->addData(array(
      'cache_lifetime' => 3600,
      'cache_tags'     => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG),
      'cache_key'      => $this->getProduct()->getId(),
   ));
}
```

But please, read the article, it'll help you

Comment: Hi Sander, thanks very much for your answer. Would it make sense to make cache_lifetime = to zero for this purpose and if the page doesn't relate to a specific product can I leave out cache key or does it need to be replaced with something else? Thanks again :)

Comment: the cache kay you can probably leave alone, and tags too, just edit lifetime I think but I used this a long time back so maybe do some experimenting ;)